# Definition of a trans-Earth injection

Tags: orbital-mechanics, terminology, earth

Should every "[propulsion maneuver used to set a spacecraft on a trajectory which will intersect the Earth's Sphere of influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Earth_injection)" be called a trans-Earth injection?

Regardless where the spacecraft leaves from, as long as it doesn't make use of any gravitational assistance from any planet would it be a TEI?

Would it still be a TEI if the craft executed a deceleration burn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how it is commonly used. If you were in a parking orbit around Mars, it is *imaginable* that the burn that brought you on the transfer back to earth wold be called a TEI. The TEI from Apollo is also a deceleration wrt. to Earth, just like a TEI from Mars would be a deceleration wrt. the Sun.

> In 2004, from outside the Earth-Moon system, the Stardust probe comet dust return mission performed TEI after visiting Comet Wild 2. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Earth_injection))

Most commonly the term is used for return from lunar orbit, but some papers have begun to distinguish this by calling those burns "*lunar* trans-earth injection" (e.g. [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Simple-Targeting-Procedure-for-Lunar-Trans-Earth-Robinson-Geller/523775a9c1327eea8944d1aee0485d5dec832d7a)) to highlight the difference from other TEI.

However, this is *descriptive*, not *prescriptive*. People will understand what kind of burn is meant if you use that term. But it doesn't describe a mandatory rule.

It kind of like saying "A red car is a car that is painted red." and then asking "Should every car that is painted red be called a red car"? The answer is no, depending on the situation other names or descriptions might be more suitable.